# OMOptim not loading whole Modelica library[MSL]

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to use OMOptim for the first time.

I want to run optimisation for code written in openmodelica that includes the following:

```
Modelica.Blocks.Sources.TimeTable solarThermal(table = [0:30:10800,100:10:3700]);
Modelica.Blocks.Sources.TimeTable solar(table = [0:30:10800,200:10:3800]);
Modelica.Blocks.Sources.TimeTable heatDemand(table = [0,450;3600,470;7200,400;10800,500]);
Modelica.Blocks.Sources.TimeTable electricityDemand(table =     
[0,300;3600,500;7200,400;10800,300]);
```

I defined in settings of omoptim that path to modelica library is C:/OpenModelica1.9.1Beta1/lib/omlibrary/Modelica 3.2.1/package.mo where TimeTable is located. Then I go Models=> Load Modelica Library.

But when it tries to load it, I get tons of error messages like this:

```
OMC : isClass(Modelica.SIunits.LossAngle)
[18:46:32] false
[18:46:32] OMC : isClass(Modelica.SIunits.Conductance)
[18:46:32] false
[18:46:32] OMC : isClass(Modelica.SIunits.Admittance)
[18:46:32] false
[18:46:32] OMC : isClass(Modelica.SIunits.ModulusOfAdmittance)
[18:46:32] false
[18:46:32] OMC : isClass(Modelica.SIunits.Susceptance)
[18:46:32] false
[18:46:32] OMC : isClass(Modelica.SIunits.InstantaneousPower)
[18:46:32] false
[18:46:32] OMC : isClass(Modelica.SIunits.ActivePower)
[18:46:32] false
...
```

It loads something like 50% of library. It doesn't load TimeTable library which I need. Am I doing something wrong and how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Modelica Standard Library has dependences to ModelicaServices. So you need also to load Modelica 3.2.1/ModelicaServices/package.mo.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is that the Modelica path should be set to:

`C:/OpenModelica1.9.1Beta1/lib/omlibrary`

Although, strangely, I thought it was automatically set to that.  But perhaps OMOptim or your scripts change that.

In other words, don't point it to the `package.mo` file and don't point it to `Modelica 3.2.1`.  Point it to the directory that contains the `Modelica 3.2.1` folder.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I didn't change anything. It was default settings. I cannot point it to  C:/OpenModelica1.9.1Beta1/lib/omlibrary because it needs specific file and not general folder. ( if I set it for folder, load library is grey and I cannot click on it)